# what is the type of: matches m s = m == fromSing s?

Tags: haskell, singleton-type

Using the [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) library, this simple function compiles and works. But, ghci and ghc disagree about the type signature of it, and if either of their suggestions is pasted into the code, it will fail to compile.

What type signature will GHC accept? ghc-7.10.3, singletons-2.0.1

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies, GADTs, UndecidableInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.Proxy (KProxy(..))
import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.Prelude

-- ghc rejects this type signature, but if I leave it off, ghci :t shows exactly this.
matches :: (Eq (DemoteRep 'KProxy), SingKind 'KProxy) => DemoteRep 'KProxy -> Sing a -> Bool
matches m s = m == fromSing s

t :: Sing True
t = sing

demo :: Bool
demo = matches True t
```

GHC's error with above type signature:

```
Couldn't match type ‘DemoteRep 'KProxy’ with ‘DemoteRep 'KProxy’
NB: ‘DemoteRep’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The kind variable ‘k2’ is ambiguous
Use -fprint-explicit-kinds to see the kind arguments
Expected type: DemoteRep 'KProxy -> Sing a -> Bool
  Actual type: DemoteRep 'KProxy -> Sing a -> Bool
In the ambiguity check for the type signature for ‘matches’:
  matches :: forall (k :: BOX)
                    (k1 :: BOX)
                    (k2 :: BOX)
                    (k3 :: BOX)
                    (a :: k3).
             (Eq (DemoteRep 'KProxy), SingKind 'KProxy) =>
             DemoteRep 'KProxy -> Sing a -> Bool
To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
In the type signature for ‘matches’:
  matches :: (Eq (DemoteRep KProxy), SingKind KProxy) =>
             DemoteRep KProxy -> Sing a -> Bool
```

`ghc -Wall` suggests a different type signature, but the `BOX` stuff won't be accepted either:

```
Top-level binding with no type signature:
         matches :: forall (k :: BOX) (a :: k).
                    (Eq (DemoteRep 'KProxy), SingKind 'KProxy) =>
                    DemoteRep 'KProxy -> Sing a -> Bool
```

Comment: BTW I have a reason to want to write the type signature down. In the code where I'm using this, I need to add some additional constraints to a function, and since I can't write down the type of a function that uses this, I can't add my extra constraints.

Comment: I'm justified in my request because falling to include the error message would justify closing the question as off-topic. Questions about debugging should include any relevant error messages or unexpected behavior.

Comment: You should now follow GHC's advice and run it with `-fprint-explicit-kinds`. Somewhere, there's a kind variable `k2` coming up that isn't getting pinned down the way it should be. `AllowAmbiguousTypes` may be able to help by moving the error to the call site, where its cause may be more intuitive (no guarantees, but it's likely).

Comment: -fprint-explicit-kinds indeed shows differing kind variables, but I can't tell where they're coming from.

Comment: AllowAmbiguousTypes does not make ghc accept the type signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'KProxy` at the type level is like `Proxy` at the value level: it has a phantom. Just as we write `Proxy :: Proxy a` with the phantom type `a` at the value level, we have to turn on kind signatures and write `'KProxy :: KProxy k` with a phantom kind `k` at the type level. Hopefully that analogy makes a kind of sense. Here's what it looks like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies, GADTs, UndecidableInstances, FlexibleContexts, KindSignatures #-}

import Data.Proxy (KProxy(..))
import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.Prelude

matches ::
  ( Eq (DemoteRep ('KProxy :: KProxy k))
  , SingKind ('KProxy :: KProxy k)
  ) => DemoteRep ('KProxy :: KProxy k) -> Sing (a :: k) -> Bool
matches m s = m == fromSing s
```

This type variable `k` will occur in both `DemoteRep ...` and `Sing ...`, which is what lets us type-check `m == fromSing s`.

GHCi, though sweet and usually smart, has no idea that the type signature needs "another level of indirection" and needs an introduced kind variable.

### Aside

I would caution aginst the majority opinion here that `-fprint-explicit-kinds` is helpful:

```
λ> :t matches
matches
  :: (Eq (DemoteRep * ('KProxy *)), SingKind * ('KProxy *)) =>
     DemoteRep * ('KProxy *) -> Sing * a -> Bool
```

That, to me, doesn't really point a finger at what's happening here. I was only able to piece together everything by looking up the signatures for `DemoteRep`, `'KProxy`, and `Sing` with the handy-dandy `:info` command.

Comment: Ew, gross! :-( Is that ... kind application or something?

Comment: That does make sense! After all, DemoteRep instances do the very same thing.

Comment: So, thank you for a great answer.. But, my, it seems that ghc could do a better job with the types it shows for this.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that you're using (essentially) a kind class, but you're not pinning down kinds properly. In particular, the three occurrences of `'KProxy` could all refer to *different* kinds. A common approach would be to *name* the proxy using an equality constraint, and use that name repeatedly. This saves a bit of typing compared to giving every proxy a signature:

```
matches :: (kproxy ~ ('KProxy :: KProxy k),
            Eq (DemoteRep kproxy),
            SingKind kproxy)
        => DemoteRep kproxy
            -> Sing (a :: k) -> Bool
```

This makes it clear that the proxies should all be the same, and in particular should have the same kind as the type passed to `Sing`.